# Differences in Javascript date in XP and OSX

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getTime();
var age = Math.floor(date/1000 - time);
```

`time` is just a UNIX timestap like `1434168603` retrieved from a table.

If I `console.log(time)`, both numbers are equal on XP and Mac OSX (Chrome). However if I `console.log(date/1000)`, for example one is `1433914098` (rounded) on XP but `1434168768` (rounded) on OSX, leading to incorrect submission time on XP. On OSX it's correct.

What is causing this?

Comment: The OS should not really matter, the browser might, what one on XP using? That being said I highly doubt that the browser is doing division wrongly. Those are probably from different `date` values.

Comment: Both are using Chrome. I downloaded the XP version just a few days ago (virtual machine).

Comment: You can follow [this](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/226287-the-time-difference-problem-between-windows-mac/) link .